# dynamic structure reference, error adding field

Tags: matlab, dynamic, struct, field

I am fairly new to MATLAB. I have a function that outputs a `struct`. I start out with a `struct` with no fields and then add fields as I go through an entire text file.

Here is some of my code:

```
tline = fgetl(fid);
test = struct;
name = 'ignore';
curr = [];
while ischar(tline)
    ...
    test.(name) = curr;
    ...
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

`name` and `curr` change many times, but `name` is always a string and `curr` is always an array.  I get the error `"Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name."` because of the line `test.(name) = curr;`

I tried the same code in the command line and it works fine. I'm really unsure why it's not working. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It would be interesting to know what `name` is when the code fails.  You could add the following to your script `dbstop if error` and then let it go.  When the error arises, the debugger will stop at the line that generated the error.  Perhaps there is something strange with the name value at that iteration…  Also, if you are using `ischar(tline)` to determine if you are at the end of the file or not, an alternative is `~feof(fid)` (for end of file).

Comment: Note that I was able to get your code to run fine (reading from some file, creating a different field on each iteration of the while loop).  Did the error message say that this was the line that was causing the problem?  Is `name` or `test` ever used in another context?  I can easily generate the same error message with `cos.(34)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `eval` to evaluate that particular line of interest.  What `eval` will do is that it takes a string and actually evaluates what that string is in the MATLAB command prompt.  As an example, if you typed in `s = 1:5` in the command prompt, you can do the same thing with `eval`: `eval('s = 1:5');`.  This is pretty innocuous, but `eval` is great if you want to create a command where you have a bunch of strings that dynamically change often.

Also, the brackets around the `(name)` doesn't make any sense.  It looks like you're trying to call a function when you're not.

As such, try doing this:

```
tline = fgetl(fid);
test = struct;
name = 'ignore';
curr = [];
while ischar(tline)
    ...
    str = ['test.' name ' = curr;'];
    eval(str);
    ...
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

What this code will do is that it will add a field designated with the string found in `name` to the `struct`, and it will assign this field with the array stored in `curr`.

That should hopefully do it!